# Rutas opcionales en Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer rutas opcionales?

Por ejemplo:

```
@app.route(r'/contacts/<key>/<name>?', methods=['GET'])
def contact_deatils(key, name = None):
   print(key, name)

   return 'mensaje de prueba'
```

si colocar parámetros
 a las rutas si, pero también que sea opcionales por ejemplo. Tengo esto en las rutas `'/contacts/<key>/<name>?'`
si coloco la url `/contacts/1/`, que me dejara visualizar la pagina, pero me sale un errror y me obliga colocar los dos parámetros. Y al colocar la url `/contacts/1/nombre/`, tambiem me muestre la página

Comment: Hola, no entiendo a qué te refieres con opcionales. ¿Te refieres a que si no sa pasa un valor para `name` entonces que quede como `None`?

Comment: @César si exacto, ademas de eso que deje mostrar las vista, por ejemplo si coloco la url `/contacts/1/`, que me dejara ver pero me sale un errror. Y al colocar la url `/contacts/1/nombre/`, tambiem me muestre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es posible usar múltiples rutas para la misma función de tal forma que tengas algo como esto:

```
@app.route('/contacts/<key>/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/contacts/<key>/<name>', methods=['GET'])
def contact_deatils(key, name=None):
   # ...
```

Tal vez tengas que validar, dentro de la función, los parámetros que has recibido. En este caso `key` siempre estará presente pero `name` tal vez sea `None`:

```
@app.route('/contacts/<key>/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/contacts/<key>/<name>', methods=['GET'])
def contact_deatils(key, name=None):
   # ...
   if not name:
       # Hacer algo 
   else:
       # Hacer otra cosa
```

Es sencillo.

Por cierto, creo que no son necesarias los "raw string" para las rutas: `r'...'`